# How to make CakePHP not auto-populate form values from the database?

Tags: php, cakephp, formhelper

I have a model `Report`, which is related to `Account`, and therefore has an `account_id` field.

On the Report's `edit` method, I have a form with the following field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('account_id', array(
    'div' => 'accountInput',
    'options' => $accounts,
    'default' => $currentAccountId,
));
```

(NB: in this case, the 'options' doesn't need to be explictly set thanks to auto-magic)

Now - **the real question** - if there is an existing value in the database (e.g. account_id == 1) then even if I include the `default` as 2, **value 1 still appears as selected in the html form**.

I could use a different name for the input, but I want it to save to account_id on submission.

Anyone know how to achieve this simply? (or else I add js and a hidden field or something clunky like that!)

Thanks, A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an option 'value' instead of 'default'.

Comment: Exactly!   *face-palm for it being relatively obvious*